# Framer-motion, delay rotateY while animating x

Tags: javascript, framer-motion

I'm working with Framer-motion and i'm trying to find a way to delay the the animation of rotateY while the x animates to a specific position then start the rotateY.

Is this possible in Framer motion ?

Example:

```
const variants = {
  flip: {
    rotateY: 0,
    x: -20,
    scale: 1,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1.2
    }
  },
  hidden: {
    rotateY: 180,
    x: 150,
    scale: 0.5,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure a transition per property. This allows you to add the necessary delay to `rotateY`:

```
const duration = 1.2;

const variants = {
  flip: {
    rotateY: 0,
    x: -20,
    scale: 1,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration,
      rotateY: {
        delay: duration,
        duration
      }
    }
  },
  hidden: {
    rotateY: 180,
    x: 150,
    scale: 0.5,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration,
      rotateY: {
        delay: duration,
        duration
      }
    }
  }
};
```

See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-delayed-property-4xvot).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. I didn't know you could do it by property. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

@amann's post above didn't wor for me in Sep 2020 v2.65

I had to update all relevant properties in the transition to ensure they ran in succession:

```
transition: {
      x: {
        ease: "easeInOut",
        duration: duration
      },
      rotateY: {
        duration: duration,
        delay: duration
      }
    }
```

Full example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";

const duration = 1.2;

const variants = {
  flip: {
    rotateY: 180,
    x: 150,
    transition: {
      x: {
        ease: "easeInOut",
        duration: duration
      },
      rotateY: {
        duration: duration,
        delay: duration
      }
    }
  },
  hidden: {
    rotateY: 0,
    x: -20,
    transition: {
      x: {
        ease: "easeInOut",
        duration: duration
      },
      rotateY: {
        duration: duration,
        delay: duration
      }
    }
  }
};

const Box = styled(motion.div)`
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
`;

export const Example = (props) => {
  return (
    <motion.div 
      initial={false}
      animate={props.toggle ? "flip": "hidden"}
    >
      <Box variants={variants} />
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-with-styled-components-forked-qjj6r?file=/src/Example.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can give specific values for each transition. Therefore, you can control them individually like so:

```
transition={{ 
  rotate: { duration: 1 }, 
  scale: { duration: 0.2 } 
}}
```