# how to animate below element's position smoothly when upper element is removed from DOM In framer Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

**Problem**

Layout prop animates position change of the pink div when the App component is rendered or Re-rendered but when an element is removed from the DOM it doesn't cause App re-render hence when purple div is removed from DOM the pink div snaps to top instead of animating.

How to animate pink div when purple div is removed from DOM ?

Click on toggle button to remove Purple Div

codeSandBox-- https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shirley-6e3oqi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: A mere link to an external platform is not a proper way to present such issues, a [mre] of it belongs directly into your question.

Comment: You need to ease the animation. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710958/11037284).

Comment: @A.Azarfar I tried adding ease to pink div It didn't help. The " pink div " animates smoothly to new position when the " purple div " is added to the DOM But When the " purple div " is removed from the DOM there is absolutely no animation on the " pink div " You can visit this link again [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shirley-6e3oqi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @CBroe Explaining the code to every one would be difficult Thats Is why I have created this short example to mimic the problem.

Comment: hey @shivamchandra sorry for late reply and necroposting. but i found wrapping the two div in a LayoutGroup makes it work as expected. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-lewin-zr8qqw

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't unmount the element until the animations are executed and finished. You can use the hook `useAnimationControls` provided in the module and have more control on animations.

```
import { motion, useAnimationControls } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const controls = useAnimationControls()
  const controlsTwo = useAnimationControls()
  
  const animOne = async() => await controls.start({
    scale: 0,
    transition:{
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1,
    }
  })
  const animTwo = async() => await controlsTwo.start({
    y: -232,
    transition:{
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1,
    }
  })


  const toggle = () => {
    animOne()
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      animTwo()
    }, 300)
  }


  
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button onClick={() => toggle()}>Toggle</button>
          <motion.div
            className="purple-div"
            initial={{ y: 10 }}
            animate={controls}
          >
            Press toggle btn & Look at Lower Div
          </motion.div>
      <motion.div
        layout
        className="pink-div"
        initial={{ y: -100 }}
        animate={controlsTwo}
      >
        Look At Me
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shirley-6e3oqi?file=/src/App.js) is a simple example of the situation. In my project I am conditionally rendering an element So The element  will get unmounted when the rendering conditions are not satisfied.
 Why did you say not to unmount the object please explain...

Comment: @shivamchandra in order to run the animation smoothly, you need to NOT unmount the element until the animation is finished. then, use can unmount it. because if you unmount it before the finish time, the other one would move quickly to the top